# OpenGL Triangle fan

Tags: opengl

I have a vertex buffer of points which are to be the center of each circle (triangle fan).  how do I take these, lets say draw 10 triangles around this point, then move onto the next point?  I haven't been able to find any example code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to `glEnd()` then `glBegin()` if you're using the old pipeline.

If you're issuing draw calls, you can use the primitive restart function, where an index can be designated as beginning a new primitive. All credit to [datenwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524368/datenwolf) for pointing that out, I've clearly blanked it from my memory.

Personally however I still think that you're better off just using indexed triangles, and then you can re-use whatever vertices you want, whenever you want. It's simpler and the driver/hardware will thank you for it.

(in other words, don't use `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` - just use `GL_TRIANGLES`. It's all the hardware draws anyway).

Comment: Primitive restart index has been around for ages. Not downvoting because of cristmas, but your answer is inaccurate.

Comment: @datenwolf you're right, and I've corrected my answer with full credit. I've also upvoted your answer. Merry Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using primitive restart index. You set a special index value (usually the largest number representable by the type used for indexing). Then whenever this index is encountered in the index buffer a new primitive is started, as if multiple calls to glDraw… had been issued.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glPrimitiveRestartIndex.xml

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I just keep thinking of the poor driver having to reformat all the data for the hardware...